# Google Chrome on Kali Linux will not launch

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I'm using Kali Linux amd64 and installed Google Chrome stable release from the official Google Chrome site but it is not launching nor showing any errors

i have tried launching it from the command line but it won't give any output.

System information:

- Intel Core i3 64bit
- 4 GB Ram

What I have tried:

- reinstalled many times no luck
- removed pepper-flash no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create standard user (root is default) and run it with him.
If you want other solutions please use google. There are many but this is the simplest.

EDIT (as root):

> 1. `cd /opt/google/chrome`
> 2. Launching chrome simply will not work because in Kali linux we are the root user, chrome wants us to be another user. So launch it like
>      this First make a directory for the chrome user storage mkdir
>      /root/chrome
>
>    Then start it like this: `./chrome --user-data-dir /root/chrome &`
>
>    The `&` so that we can continue using the shell while chrome is open.
> 3. Anyhow close chrome and lets setup the shortcuts and alias. By now `/opt/google/chrome` is not on your `PATH` so just typing chrome from
>      anywhere wont launch it. Easy fix set an alias or a symlink.
>
>    First though lets make a start script for step 8 to always happen
>
>    `cd /opt/google/chrome touch startchrome.sh chmod +x startchrome.sh vim
>      startchrome.sh`
> 4. In the script just put this:
>
>    `/opt/google/chrome --user-data-dir /root/chrome &`
> 5. Now make the alias - but we wont go that way because we will also need to make that permanent in /root/.bashrc and thats a bigger hassle
>      then the next symlink method:
>
>    `alias chrome=/opt/google/chrome/startchrome.sh`
>
>    Or make the symlink:
>
>    `ln -s /opt/google/chrome/startchrome.sh /usr/local/bin/chrome`
> 6. Now to make the desktop shortcut, this app comes with Kali linux but double check
>
>    `apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-desktop-item-edit /root/Desktop/
>      --create-new`
> 7. Now Leave the type as Application and set the Name to "Chrome" and the Command type out or browse to `/opt/google/chrome/startchrome.sh`
>      and hit OK

[Source](http://www.kossboss.com/kalichrome)

Comment: but i want to run this as root user.i had it working before the update with --user-data-dir but now after the update it is not working at all

Answer (score 2):

You can open google chrome with a terminal like this using this command,

```
google-chrome --no-sandbox
```

**OR**

You can follow these steps if you want to open it directly.

1) open the terminal and type `nano google-chrome`.

2) In the last line use `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --no-sandbox` instead of `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `google-chrome` script using the following command:

   `nano /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`
2. At the end of the file, you will see something like this:

   `exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"`

Just add `--no-sandbox` at the end of line. Make it look like below:

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --no-sandbox
```

This worked for me with Kali 4.19.0 (2019-06-20) version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as I am a new to Kali Linux.

I followed the following steps to run applications as low privileged (non-root) user as some are recommended to run as low privileged (non-root) user for safety reasons, e.g. browsers and editors etc.

1. Create a low privileged user account.
2. Run command `service ssh restart`.
3. Run command `ssh nonrootuser@rootuser -X` Here *nonrootuser* is your low privileged username and *rootuser* is your root user name . After that it is going to ask your low privileged user account password.
4. Next command to run application. For e.g. in my case `google-chrome` to run the Chrome browser and now you run Chrome as non root user.